# Change AppBar title dynamically in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a reusable AppBar widget in different class. Have to set the app bar title from an API response. Once the appBar title is set, it should be same for all the screens.

AppBar.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  CustomAppBar({Key key})
      : preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  final Size preferredSize; // default is 56.0

  @override
  _CustomAppBarState createState() => _CustomAppBarState();
}

class _CustomAppBarState extends State<CustomAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text('Emotely'),
      flexibleSpace: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [themeColor, themeColorLight],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

MainScreen.dart

```
//api response

    upload(String base64Image) {
        var body = jsonEncode({"image": base64Image});
        http
            .post(api, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: body)
            .then((result) {
          print(result.body);
          setStatus(result.statusCode == 200 ? result.body : errMessage);
        })

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(), //Need to change the AppBar Title here
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a final variable to your custom app bar

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {

  CustomAppBar(String title) {
    this.preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
    this.title = title; // <-- add This
  }

  @override
  final Size preferredSize; // default is 56.0
  final String title // <-- Add this 

  @override
  _CustomAppBarState createState() => _CustomAppBarState();
}
```

And now inside the `_CustomAppBarState` use `widget.title`.
example:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return AppBar(
  title: Text(widget.title), // <-- add this
 .....
 .....
```

And now declare a String variable inside your main state full widget class:

```
String myAppBarTitle = ""; // <-- Add this

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: CustomAppBar(myAppBarTitle), // <-- Add this
  .....
  .....
  ) 
};
```

Whenever you want to change the title, simply use setState:

```
setState(() {
  myAppBarTitle = "some new title";
});
```

Also I would suggest changing the custom app bar into a state **Less** widget because as far as I can see you are not changing the state of the app bar.

Comment: This works only for one screen. I have 5 screen. Once i set the state of app bar title it should remain the same in other screen as well.

Comment: can u modify the answer with that. Then i can mark this as correct

Comment: can you help me to set the app bar title state to all screens ??